# Hamburger menu doesn't toggle

Tags: menu, toggle

In mobile view the hamburger doesn't toggle to the menu items when pressed

I have tried reordering the CSS .responsive code but it doesn't work

```
nav > ul > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  /*selects the list elements in the navigation class */
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #49cde4;
}
nav > ul > li > a:active {
  color: #535461 0.3;
}
.navtoggle {
  /* gives space between logo and menu*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navtoggle li:not(:last-child) {
  /* To remove the menu items in small screen */
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}
.navtoggle.responsive nav {
  position: relative;
  padding: 24px 0 0;
  display: block;
}
.navtoggle li .icon {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 0;
  top: 2px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navtoggle.responsive li:last-child {
  /*doesn't show hamburger when toggled*/
  display: none;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}
.navtoggle.responsive li {
  /* Should toggle on the menu list */
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This is the JavaScript

```
   function menuToggle() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myNavtoggle');
    if (x.className === 'navtoggle') {
        x.className += ' responsive';
    } else {
        x.className = 'navtoggle';
    }
  }
```

This is the HTML

```
          <nav>
            <ul class="navigation">
              <li><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
              <li><a href="cira.html">CIRA</a></li>
              <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a></li>
              <li>
                <a
                  href="javascript:void(0);"
                  class="icon"
                  onclick="menuToggle()">
                  <img src="img/portfolio/bars-solid.svg"
                  style="width: 48px; height: 48px" alt="menu icon">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

When I have tested the index.html file it shows error that the myToggle is not defined. I have tried to find the error, but I'm at a loss to find where I'm going wrong.